# Reload img onReady function again and again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a situation in which I have to update the marker on an image repeatedly i.e every second. I am fetching the latest co-ordinates from my server.

What am doing is that under `$(document).ready(function () { });` function am calling the php file and fetching the latest co-ordinates. Later on ajax's `complete:` am putting the marker on the image(Using a function). After putting the marker, am again calling the `ajax function` which calls the php and fetches the new co-ordinates.

This part is fine, am getting the latest co-ord every second but when I try to plot the marker again, it just doesn't update. If I refresh the page, it works.

Am using [img viewer](https://github.com/waynegm/imgViewer2).

The snippet which might be causing issue is :

```
function reload_coord() {
            var default_notes = [   {x: convx1, y:convy1, note:"User 1"}, 
            {x: ".5", y:".5", note: 'User 2'}];
            var $imgf = $("#image_fixed").imgNotes();
            $imgf.imgNotes("import", default_notes);
            var $imgd = $("#image_dynamic").imgNotes({
                onReady: function() {
                    this.import(default_notes);
                }
            });

        }
```

I believe it's happening because of img's `onReady` function i.e it's getting loaded once I refresh the page, but after that, it's not going into `onReady` thing.

Can anyone tell me what can I do so that marker can be refreshed again and again without refreshing the whole page.

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/waynegm/imgViewer2/issues/6

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to extend the [imgViewer2](https://github.com/waynegm/imgViewer2) plugin to achieve what you want. Here is a simple extension that has a moving marker:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
;(function($) {
    $.widget("wgm.imgDynMarker", $.wgm.imgViewer2, {
/*
*   Add the marker
*/
        addMarker: function( x, y, note ) {
            var map = this.map,
                loc = this.relposToLatLng( x, y );
            this.mkr = L.marker(loc).addTo(map).bindPopup(note);
        },
/*
*   Move the marker
*/
        moveMarker: function(x,y) {
            var loc = this.relposToLatLng( x, y );
            this.mkr.setLatLng(loc);
        }
    });
    $(window).on("load", function() {
        var $img = $("#image1").imgDynMarker();
        $img.imgDynMarker('addMarker', 0.5, 0.5, "A note");
        setInterval( function() {
            var x = Math.random();
            var y = Math.random();
            $img.imgDynMarker('moveMarker', x, y );
            $img.imgDynMarker('panTo', x, y );
        }, 1000 );
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, AJAX events don´t call onready triggers.
You may call it on the complete event of AJAX, but this may turn your page slugish with a few visitors.

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
 reload_coord() ;
});
```

Better set an AJAX call every second and half or so.

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
 setTimeout(setTimeout(reload_coord() ), 1500);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't solve the issue. Marker is still not getting updated.

Comment: can you post a link?